# C++ How do I ensure a copy constructor does not modify an original object's pointer data member?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

I have created a date and time class with the following ctor and cpy ctor

**Date_and_Times.h**

```
class Date_and_Times {
  public:
    Date_and_Times(Date, Time *, size_t);
    Date_and_Times(const Date_and_Times&);
    ~Date_and_Times(void);

    Date_and_Times& operator=(const Date_and_Times&);
```

**Date_and_Times.cpp**

```
#include "Date_and_times.h"

Date_and_Times::Date_and_Times(Date date, Time *times, size_t N)
:_date(date), _timePtr(times), _size(N){}

Date_and_Times::Date_and_Times(const Date_and_Times& dtObjCpy)
:_date(dtObjCpy._date), _timePtr(dtObjCpy._timePtr), _size(dtObjCpy._size){}

Date_and_Times::~Date_and_Times(void) {}

Date_and_Times& Date_and_Times::operator=(const Date_and_Times &dtObj) {

  // check for self-assignment by comparing the address of
  // the implicit object and the parameter
  if(this == &dtObj)
    return *this;

  // copy
  _date = dtObj._date;
  _timePtr = dtObj._timePtr;
  _size = dtObj._size;

  // return the existing object
  return *this;
}
```

Cpy ctor is called to create a new Date and Time object:

```
Date_and_Times dTsObj2(dTsObj);
```

The **new object** is then modified:

```
dTsObj2.addFiveSecs();
```

But the **original object** is also modified. 
Execution order:

```
dTsObj.display();               // original date and time data
Date_and_Times dTsObj2(dTsObj); // copy ctor
dTsObj2.addFiveSecs();          // only the copy should be modified
dTsObj2.display();              // updated date and time data in copy
dTsObj.display();               // date and time data should be the original
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE:**

Output the object just created.

The date is: 
1/13/2016 
The times are:
**10:30:00 10:30:10 10:30:20 10:30:30 10:30:40**

Output the object just created using **copy ctor**: Note that 5 seconds has been added to each Time object for the object below.

The date is: 
 1/13/2016 
 The times are: 
 **10:30:05 10:30:15 10:30:25 10:30:35 10:30:45**

Output the **original object** again to show it was not modified by copy ctor.

The date is: 
 1/13/2016 
The times are: 
 **10:30:05 10:30:15 10:30:25 10:30:35 10:30:45**

Is there a way to keep the original object from being modified? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: The original object can't be modified by the copy constructor. Your problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You are doing a shallow copy; the two `Date_and_Times` share the same `Time`.

Comment: Well, the original object can't be modified, because you take a const reference to it. But if there is a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory inside the object, you have to allocate and initialise some new memory in the copy ctor. You want a deep copy, and not a shallow copy. I see that the timePtr is just copied by value, you should initialise a new `Time` object

Comment: While you haven't mentioned it, I guess you don't know about the so-called "Law of Three", either. It is actually a fundamental rule in C++, so search the web for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're copying the `_timePtr` *pointer*, so both objects end up pointing to the same instance of `Time`. As a result, when you modify one, they both change.

What you need to do is create a new instance of the `Time` class, copying it's contents from `dtObjCpy._timePtr`.

Comment: To clarify this last para, the object should contain a member of type `Time`  and the class can follow the Rule of Zero